# MPAndroidChart - Horizontal (left to right) gradient color in Barchart

Tags: kotlin, colors, bar-chart, gradient, mpandroidchart

I am working with Barchart of MPAndroidChart.
Is it possible to define horizontal gradient color on BarDataSet?

I know that you can set gradient color like this :

```
val dataset = BarDataSet(entries, null)
dataset.setGradientColor(startColor, endColor)
```

But the gradient is from bottom to top and I would like a gradient from left to right.

Thanks for your help!